# Are bots for Workplace by Facebook supported via the Facebook channel on Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger, facebook-workplace

I am trying to connect my bot on the Microsoft Bot Framework to a Work Chat Bot on Workplace by Facebook.

Everything appears to work the same as the regular Facebook Messenger channel:

- I can validate my Facebook Messenger credentials in Botframework (page id, app id, app secret, page access token)
- The Botframework webhook works in my Workplace custom integration settings [image: (see screenshot 1)]
- I can find my bot in Work Chat and send it messages [image: (see screenshot 2)]
- All the regular Messenger API calls work normally (e.g. setting persistent menus)
- No issues appear in the Bot Framework management console

However, the bot never answers.

Am I doing something wrong, or are bots for Workplace unsupported in Botframework?

Comment: Is your bot answering via any other channel? Let's say the webchat within the Bot Framework management portal?

Comment: @EzequielJadib Yes. It answers via webchat and Skype. I haven't configured any other channels.

Comment: What are you using for the `Facebook Page ID` in the Facebook Messenger channel? If you go to your bot's page in workplace, the ID should just be the  numeric part after the bot's name in the Url: <botName>-NNNNNNNNNNNNNNN

Comment: @DavisG.Trent BOOM! That was the problem. I was using the number from the SCIM URL. I didn't realize my bot had a page until you mentioned it.

Comment: Hi @Chris McGrath, I tried  to connect my bot on the Microsoft Bot Framework to a Work Chat Bot on Workplace by Facebook. I configured seetings like APP ID, App Secret, Token ,call back URL for page etc., But i am unable to find my bot in work place chat to send message. What am i doing wrong? could you please suggest me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Bots for Workplace by Facebook are supported via the Facebook Messenger channel on the Microsoft Bot Framework. To set it up, you need the 3 things in the screenshot above: App ID, App Secret, Access Token.

You also need the page ID. To get this, find the page for your bot by searching for `<botName>` in the Workplace search. The page ID is in the URL in the format `<botName>-NNNNNNNNNNNNNNN`.

Comment: I had configured facebook messenger channel on bot framework with all necessary information (page id, app id , app secret, token, call back url etc.,)  fetched from workplace by facebook. But i am still getting error message while sending message to bot. what am i doing wrong ?

Error: Meesage failed to send.