# Are groups in Workplace by Facebook supported via the Facebook channel on Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: azure, botframework, facebook-workplace

[IMAGE OF CHAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OfU5.png)
Good Day,
I have developed a bot via the Azure Bot Service.
The QnA bot works for employees in our Workplace tenant if they search for the bot and chat directly.

I can find the Bot using @Jargon from within a Workplace group, but, the bot does not reply in this context.
Is there support for workplace group functionality in MS Bot Framework?

Comment: This answer says yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637134/are-bots-for-workplace-by-facebook-supported-via-the-facebook-channel-on-microso

Comment: This does not answer my question.
I saw this some days ago.
My bot is up and running but does not reply FROM WITHIN A GROUP.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh, ok.  I thought maybe this was just a duplicate question (you've only been a member for three days, so I wasn't aware of the fact that you've searched previous questions).  Are you saying that even when you @mention the bot name in the group, you get no reply?

Comment: One of my co-workers just emailed that the Bot Framework does NOT support Facebook Workplace.  I apologize, I was not aware of that.

Comment: Hmm this is confusing I have my bot running in FB workplace and I and other users can chat with it so how is that possible if FB workplace is not supported?
See the thread you pasted where other developers also have Bot Framework bots running in FB workplace.
Anyway, yes when I @mention the bot from within a group then and only then it does not reply.
I will keep on searching on my own.
Cheers

Comment: You could file a feature request on the Bot Builder GitHub page. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder MS Bot Builder bots on Facebook are supported.  Facebook Workplace has no specific support.  If it is functioning, it is incidental.

Comment: Sorry for the bother.
I have been looking around on github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder am not getting how to file a feature request.
Could anyone enlighten me?
Thanks and Cheers

Comment: It is not a bother.  Here's the link for filing a new issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/new

Comment: Thanks I just figured it out:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2821